# Are primary/secondary index files really necessary? Couldn't they be RAM-structures only with little performance/reliability loss?

Tags: file

> Context: I'm an CS undergrad studying Files Organization, definitely not
> an expert, definitions below may not be correct/standard/optimal.

I'm studying `record`-`fields` files. In which each record has an unique `id`. For those who are not familiar with the concept:

> A library - a collection of `(id, *fields)` eg `(id, author, book)` - could be represented trough a `RecordsFields` file, a binary block of `Fields` delimited by pre-defined separators.

Say :

> 1. Records are `(3,Jhon Green, The fault in Our Stars)`, `(8, J.K Rowling, Harry Potter 1)` and `(5,Jhon Green, Looking for Alaska)`

> 2. Separators are `Sep1`=`','` and`Sep2`=`'\n'` (assumption: no `field` contains `|` or `\n`):

**RecordsFields.file:**

```
# RecordFile is binary, encoders/decoders are needed
3|Jhon Green|The Fault in Our Stars
8|J.K Rowling|Harry Potter 1
5|Jhon Green|Looking for Alaska
```

Which could be represented in `PrimaryIndex` and `SecondaryIndex` files for efficiently accessing/manipulating records with less Disk Accesses.

`PrimaryIndex` stores only the `id`s and `Byte Offset` that can be used to recover `Record` in `RecordFile` with little `RecordsFile.seek()` based on `byte_offset`s:

**PrimaryIndex.file**:

```
3|byte_offset_1
8|byte_offset_2
5|byte_offset_3
```

Similarly, `SecondaryIndex` is also a file that represents `RecordsFields.file`, but instead of grouping items by `id`s, they group it through by an specific `field`, either strongly bonded (`field` points to a list `byte_offset`) or weakly bonded(`field` points to a list of `id`)

**SecondaryIndex.file**:

```
# weakly bonded, indexed by author
Jhon Green|3|5
J.K Rowling|8
```

Although in the examples above`PrimaryIndex` and `SecondaryIndex` don't seem to be significantly smaller than `RecordFields` file, in a scenario where `record`s have dozens or hundreds of `field`s they would be.

In fact, I'm assuming both `PrimaryIndex` and `SecondaryIndex` fit whole in `RAM`, unlike `RecordFields`. If that's not the case, a structure like `b-tree` could be used.

The idea is to operate `PrimaryIndex` and `SecondaryIndex` via RAM, updating `RecordFields` after a batch of operations to reduce disk access - which is way too slow. For example, let's say we're using python:

**RAM_primary_index**

```py
RAM_primary_index = {
    3: ('Jhon Green', 'The Fault in Our Stars'),
    8: ('J.K Rowling', 'Harry Potter 1'),
    5: ('Jhon Green', 'Looking for Alaska')
}
```

**RAM_secondary_index**

```py
RAM_secondary_index = {
    'Jhon Green' : [3,5],
    'J.K Rowling': [8],
}
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that `file.write()` behavior is to **override**, not to **shift**, as **"SHIFTING" INSIDE FILES IS EXTREMELY COSTLY AND SHOULD BE AVOIDED**, as it requires re-writing many blocks of data in secondary memory.

For example, it's not trivial to "edit" record `(8, 'J.K Rowling', 'Harry Potter 1')` to `(8, 'J.K Rowling', 'Harry Potter 81234567')`, as `len(Harry potter 285') - len('Harry Potter 1') = 7`, and trying to write the new `field` on old `field` memory address would override the 7 subsequent characters `\n5|Jhon` to `1234567`.

One option to solve this is to use `isActive` binary fields (`0` or `1`) and modify common operations behaviour:

1. `ADD`: append a new record to end of files, with `isActive` = 1.
2. `DELETE`: flip `isActive` from `1` to `0` (This is allowed, field is guaranteed to have constant size)
3. `EDIT`: "delete" old record, append new to end of file.
4. `SEARCH`: Ignore records with `isActive` == `0`

Another issue is that **program can be interrupted** before buffered operations operated on `RAM_index` are actually updated to their `index.file`.

The workarounds I've came across to those issues are:

- 1. Don't buffer operations, every `RAM_index` `ADD`, `DELETE` and `EDIT` operation must be propagated to `PrimaryIndex.file`, `SecondaryIndex.file` and `RecordFields.file`
- 2. Don't trust `Index.file`s Assume they're wrong and re-create them from `RecordFields.file` every time program startup.

  - 2.1 Batch read `RecordFields.file` read into N `buffered_records_fields` `string`s.
  - 2.2 For each`buffered_record_fields`, update`RAM_primary_index` and `RAM_secondary_index`
  - 2.3 Dump `RAM_primary_index` and `RAM_secondary_index` into two string buffers, `buffered_primary_index` and `buffered_secondary_index`
    `buffered_secondary_index`
  - 2.4 Write/Override `index.file`s with the buffers every program startup.
- 3. Same for 2, but implement a hash that represents de state of the files and store it on their first line. Check hashes before assuming files are outdated. (I didn't find sources for implementing this hash, though)

### Finally, the question

Why is having primary/secondary files necessary first place if:

1. We're assuming they fit into RAM (Otherwise, use b-tree)
2. We would have to load `primary_index.file` and `secondary_index.file` into RAM anyway on start, which is less costly then loading `records_fields.file`, but we pay the price updating index files each operation if operations are not buffered.
3. If we buffer operations, we may have un-synchronized files that need to be reconstructed anyway

Wouldn't it be better if we simply just use RAM indexes and don't store the files as they're not trust-able? Is there any trade-off i'm not seeing?